# Unable to load js into html

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I have written spring mvc project
I have written following in my context.xml to locate resources

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/js/" />
```

also I tried

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/js/**" location="/resources/js/" />
```

Following is my html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Home Page</title>
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/studentApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body></html>
```

Following is a directory structure

[image]

In javascript console it shows,

> GET //localhost:8080/resources/js/studentApp.js 400 (Bad Request)

Why it is not loading/not found studentApp.js? Please make correct if I am wrong :)

Thank you.

Comment: Do *any* requests work, e.g., can you successfully retrieve `home.html` or any other file under `resources`? Or anything at the top level like `index.html`?

Comment: yes. If I put content of script into html in script tag, it works fine. But for separate js file it fails.

Comment: Do your server logs show anything?

Comment: It is showing nothing. Just showing error in js console as shown in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not entering the correct path name. Just include project name in path.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="--YOUR PROJECT NAME--/resources/js/studentApp.js"></script>
```

or refer to a path relative to the current directory while loading (ie: use a *relative path*). This is done by inserting **`"./ "`** .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./resources/js/studentApp.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. @Bogdan Emil Mariesan